# how to get key and how to add more values?

Tags: java, hashmap, key

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    LinkedHashMap<String,String>category1=new LinkedHashMap();

    category1.put("action","die hard");
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer=s.nextLine();
    if (category1.containsKey(answer))
        System.out.println(category1.get("action"));
    if (category1.containsValue(answer))
        System.out.println(category1.keySet());
```

How to get the key when the user answer with it's specific value, and how to add more values to one key?

Comment: "How to get the key when the user answer with it's specific value" and "how to get the key when the user answer with it's specific value" are two separate questions. Please [ask one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).

Comment: Anyway it looks like you need two maps: (1) `category -> [collection,of,movies]` (2) `movie->category`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** The map collection, **does not** support multiple values under the same key, it will **override** whatever was stored there before.

**2.** However, you can change it from `<String,String>` to `<String,List<String>>`, thus gaining the ability to accumulate the answers from the client into the list. The key will refer to **only** one object, the list of Strings, but the list itself can hold many values.

**3.** In order to add more Strings to the list, you will need to retrieve the list by the desired key, and then add your new String to it.

Here is some code that implements the idea:

```
private void test(){
        Map<String, List<String>> categories = new HashMap<>();
        String answerFromClient = "Some text";
        List<String> actionAnswers = categories.get("action");
        if (actionAnswers == null){
            actionAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
            actionAnswers.add(answerFromClient);
            categories.put("action",actionAnswers);
        }
        else{
            actionAnswers.add(answerFromClient);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you actually tried that? I don't think simply changing the second type parameter to `List<String>` will magically make it accept multiple strings without changing the code.

Comment: Of course you will need to change the code to support the list of strings, but I was just giving a general idea.

Comment: then that should be said in the answer. Simply changing the parameter will not suffice.

Comment: I edited the answer,and provided an example.

Comment: you could also use a multivaluemap implementation. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.2/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html

Comment: Sure, for simplicity, however I believe that under the hood, their implementation is similar.

Comment: @DanielB.: yes, that will probably work. But I would think that `Map<,>` is simply not the correct vehicle for multiple values per key.

Comment: Do you have a better data structure in mind?